# how to display on map the distance between two geopoints?

Tags: android

I am developing an app where in user has to record location and then locate the car.When he selects locate car option the car that is parked should be displayed.I calculate the distance but distance always shows 0 metres..i dono why?can anyone tell how to show the the distance between person and the car parked on map... i want to show the parked car on the map

Comment: Post your piece of code.

Comment: you should definitely post your piece of code, otherwise it is a pain in the ass to "guess" what you have achieved so far and what your specific problem is...

Answer (score 0):

you saved the position of the parked car? you've got the actual position of the person? so, then you should be able to calculate the difference and get at least the distance (at least of the line in sight)...

Answer (score 0):

Use this function which calculates the real distance:

```
public static double distFrom (double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2 ) 
{
    double earthRadius = 3958.75;
    double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
    double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
    double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
    Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
    Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    double dist = earthRadius * c;

    int meterConversion = 1609;

    return new Double(dist * meterConversion).doubleValue();
}
```

and use it like this:

```
double distance = 0;
distance=distFrom(latA,lngA,latB,lngB);
```

if you want to convert the double to integer use this:

```
int distance=0;
distance=(int) distFrom(latA,lngA,latB,lngB);
```